# How to enable app-service-authentication and logging into a blob via ARM-Template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

How to enable app-service-authentication and logging into a blob via ARM-Template?

hello everybody, i have a question i want to activate the app-service-authentication for anonymous requests and also the logging of everything that could happen in the website into a blob of a storageaccount via the resource template. what should i add to the template-json-file to do that?

thanks for every help

**Edit:**

I found out something.
with this snippet it work but that are not the correct settings

`"properties": {
                "name": "<#= website.Name #>",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "alwaysOn": true,
                    "siteAuthEnabled": true,
                    "siteAuthSettings": null,
                    "httpLoggingEnabled": true,
                    "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                    "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": true
                },`

now it looks like so:

[image]

but that is how it should be looking for:

[image]

Comment: What is the Authentication Providers which you plan to use when you enable the App Service Authentication?

Comment: i don't want to use any authentication provider,I'm using the graph api for sign up and log in, i only want to activate anonymous requests to this website

Comment: So you mean you want to enable App Service authentication and allow anonymous requests? Is this correct?

Comment: right that's what i'm looking for

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Any concern, please let me know.

Comment: yeah got it, thank you all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your scenario, I have deployed my ARM template to enable Application Logging and Web server logging against Blob Storage, enable App Service Authentication and allow Anonymous requests for my Web App. Here are some detailed steps, you could refer to them.

1.Create Azure Resource Group project and add the Web App template;

2.Add "MONITORING > Diagnostic logs" configuration as follows:

[image]

3.Add "SETTINGS > Authentication/Authorization" configuration as follows:

[image]

4.Deploy the Web App and check it on Azure Portal:

[image]

Here is my website.json, you could refer to it.

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "logs",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]" ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "websiteLogs"
          },
          "properties": {
            "applicationLogs": {
              "fileSystem": {
                "level": "Off"
              },
              "azureTableStorage": {
                "level": "Off",
                "sasUrl": null
              },
              "azureBlobStorage": {
                "level": "Error",
                "sasUrl": "https://{your-storageaccount-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}?{sasToken}",
                "retentionInDays": null
              }
            },
            "httpLogs": {
              "fileSystem": {
                "retentionInMb": 35,
                "retentionInDays": null,
                "enabled": false
              },
              "azureBlobStorage": {
                "sasUrl":"https://{your-storageaccount-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}?{sasToken}",
                "retentionInDays": null,
                "enabled": true
              }
            },
            "failedRequestsTracing": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "detailedErrorMessages": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "authsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]" ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "websiteAuthSettings"
          },
          "properties": {
            "enabled": true,
            "httpApiPrefixPath": null,
            "unauthenticatedClientAction": 1,
            "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
            "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
            "defaultProvider": 0,
            "clientId": null,
            "clientSecret": null,
            "issuer": null,
            "allowedAudiences": null,
            "additionalLoginParams": null,
            "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
            "googleClientId": null,
            "googleClientSecret": null,
            "googleOAuthScopes": null,
            "facebookAppId": null,
            "facebookAppSecret": null,
            "facebookOAuthScopes": [
              ""
            ],
            "twitterConsumerKey": null,
            "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
            "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
            "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
            "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": [
              ""
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Additionally, you could retrieve the configurations from [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com). Here is the screenshot for you to have a better understanding of the ARM template:

[image]

Comment: What does "defaultProvider" set to 0 indicate in the authSetting config? Thanks.

Comment: The properties `unauthenticatedClientAction` and `defaultProvider` are used to configure "Action to take when request is not authenticated". When you allow Anonymous requests, then `unauthenticatedClientAction` would be set as 1. When you disable Anonymous requests, you need to configure the login provider for the request that is not authenticated. At this point, `unauthenticatedClientAction` would be set as 0 and the `defaultProvider` is the index value of the provider (e.g. AAD=0, Twitter=4) you chose.

Comment: well all settings in the portal are correct now but it isn't working it only works if i set the same blobs by hand and save it again, any idea why?

Comment: I assumed that you could try to [enable storage logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Enabling-Storage-Logging-and-Accessing-Log-Data?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to collect log data that relates to the operations against your storage account.

Answer (score 2):

WebApp logging and authentication can be enabled via following resources in your template

```
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "logs",
      "type": "config",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]" ],
      "properties": {
        "applicationLogs": {
          "fileSystem": {
            "level": "off"
          },
          "azureTableStorage": {
            "level": "off",
            "sasUrl": null
          },
          "azureBlobStorage": {
            "level": "off",
            "sasUrl": null,
            "retentionInDays": null
          }
        },
        "httpLogs": {
          "fileSystem": {
            "retentionInMb": 35,
            "retentionInDays": null,
            "enabled": true
          },
          "azureBlobStorage": {
            "sasUrl": null,
            "retentionInDays": null,
            "enabled": false
          }
        },
        "failedRequestsTracing": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "detailedErrorMessages": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "authsettings",
      "type": "config",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]" ],
      "properties": {
        "enabled": false,
        "isAadAutoProvisioned": false
      }
    }
```

If you are not sure, what values should be in template. 
Do following:

1. Provision Web App through the portal
2. Enable necessary settings
3. Go to https://resources.azure.com/ and check how template is configured for your Web App
4. Make changes in your template json file

Comment: yeah i know but the problem is that i can configure everything in the portal but the automation script wouldn't be different. it shows me the basics to get this ressource group or the resource template that i created

Answer (score 0):

​**Log all the things**

You could enable Diagnostics Logging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)
for your App Service and add it to your App Service Website by following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template

For a general logging solution that helps you keep track of (almost) everything that happens in an App Service web site you could use Application Insights (AI). You can add Application Insights to your ARM template by following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-powershell#create-an-azure-resource-manager-template. This will help you setup AI for your web and define any specific tracking and telemetry you want to log.

Basically this is what you need to add to your ARM template in order to add AI to an App Service:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-08-01",
      "location": "[parameters('appLocation')]",
      "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "[parameters('applicationType')]",
        "ApplicationId": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "Name": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "Flow_Type": "Redfield",
        "Request_Source": "IbizaAIExtension"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('billingplan')]",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components/CurrentBillingFeatures",
      "location": "[parameters('appLocation')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "CurrentBillingFeatures": "[variables('pricePlan')]",
        "DataVolumeCap": {
          "Cap": "[parameters('dailyQuota')]",
          "WarningThreshold": "[parameters('warningThreshold')]",
          "ResetTime": "[parameters('dailyQuotaResetTime')]"
        }
      }
    },
  "__comment":"web test, alert, and any other resources go here"
  ]
```

Of course, you need to provide values for all the parameters and variables based on the price plan and quotas you want to set.

You could then setup **Continuous Export** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry) from AI to export all logged telemetry to a separate Azure Storage blob for long term retention of your logged data. Unfortunatelly you cannot setup Continuous Export from the ARM template, but it will likely be available soon: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/13718607-enable-programatic-configuration-of-continuous-exp

**Authenticate all the things**

Setting up Authentication in your App Service you can specify the authentication options as `properties` for your `WebSite` resource. I suggest you start by configuring the desired authentication model using the portal or PowerShell first and then extract the template from the resulting deployment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template as the actual properties and values to set are not well documented.

**Creating an ARM template from the portal**

You can do all the changes to your website, setup diagnostics directly in the portal and then extract a template that reflects what is currently deployed in that Resource Group.

Just go to your Resource Group and select *Automation script*, this will extract the template definition. It may not be the prettiest template or best structured, but it will contain your deployment (unless it shows a warning for some resources).

[image: Azure portal Resource Group > Automation script]

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. i never saw something like category or serviceBusRuleId in the portal.

Comment: Where do you find 'category' and 'serviceBusRuleId'? That is not information you need to setup Application Insights.

Comment: I found it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template) and yeah you need it to setup insights service I have misread

Comment: I just added some details in the answer on how you can get the template from a finished setup in the portal. I hope this will help you.